# Define a linear operator $T$ on ${\mathbb R}^3$ such that $T$ is nilpotent and satisfies conditions below?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Define a linear operator $T$ on ${\mathbb R}^3$ such that $T$ is nilpotent and satisfies

$$T([1~1~0]^t)=[0~1~0]^t, T([0~1~1]^t)=[1~0~0]^t.$$

I find one by defining $T$ by $T([1~0~0]^t)=[0~0~0]^t, T([1~1~0]^t)=[0~1~0]^t, T([0~1~1]^t)=[1~0~0]^t.$ I wonder if there is a method that can list all the linear operators?

Comment: Note: There is no such nilpotent $T$ with $T([1~0~0]^t)=[0~0~0]^t$

Comment: @Brian Moehring, Yes, You are right! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @BrianMoehring for catching an error. Hence the contorted appearance of ${1 \over 2}$ below.

Let $v_1 = (1,1,0), v_2 = (0, 1, 1)$ and $v_3 = (1, 0,1)$ just for definiteness. We are given that $T$ is nilpotent, $Tv_1 = {1 \over 2}(v_1+v_2-v_3), T v_2 ={1 \over 2}( v_1+v_3-v_2)$. Hence in the basis $v_k$ we see that $T$ has the form
$M= {1 \over 2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & a \\ 1 & -1 & b \\ -1 & 1 & c\end{bmatrix}$.

Since $M$ is nilpotent, it follows that $2M$ is nilpotent and we know that $\det (2M-\lambda I) = -\lambda^3$.

Since there is no $\lambda^2$ term  we see that $c=0$. Since $\det (2M) = 0$ we see that $b=0$. Then we can compute the $\lambda$ term to get $a=2$.

Comment: Something is weird here... we should at most be able to determine $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ up to a nonzero scalar multiple, no?

Comment: One way to look at is that the characteristic equation gives us three constraints and we have three variables. So, generically we might expect a unique solution.

Comment: All right.  I finally found the issue that was bothering me.  It's that it should be $$Tv_1 = \frac{1}{2}(v_1+v_2-v_3) \\ Tv_2 = \frac{1}{2}(v_1+v_3-v_2)$$ which was throwing everything off by a scalar multiple.  I agree there is a unique solution now.

Comment: @BrianMoehring: Thanks, I guess I have a mistake :-(

Comment: Hah, it probably doesn't matter for most people, but you had me pulling out my hair thinking I had finally lost it until I noticed that ;-)

Comment: @BrianMoehring: I understand completely.

Comment: Thank you very much! On the third line of your answer, you missed the number '1' in 1/2, a very little mistake.

Comment: @YWang: Thanks!